# Use the Exercise environment from Legrand Book template

Tags: boxes, tcolorbox, book-design

I am using the [Legrand Orange book template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book) and like the typesetting of the exercise environment. I wanted to use the same environment to just have my text within the ocre color box.  From the template:

[image]

replace the text "Exercise 2.1" by "My Text" and the rest of the text by some other verbiage.

How do I go about this? Can I just create a box around my text with the ocre color? But then what about the small filled square at the bottom right corner of the box?

Comment: The filled square can be achieved with something like this: `\hfill {\color[RGB]{234,102,26}\rule{1ex}{1ex}}`

Comment: yes what about it (small filled), you need it? or no?

Comment: yes, I would like for it to be there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The template internally uses an `eBox` environment build with `mdframed`, so you can provide a similar definition for your box:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\input{structure}

\newenvironment{myboxedtext}[1]
  {\begin{eBox}\textcolor{ocre}{{\bfseries\small\sffamily#1~}}}
  {\hfill{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{eBox}}        

\begin{document}

\begin{myboxedtext}{My text}
Some test text goes here to illustrate the use of the box defined for text.
\end{myboxedtext}

\end{document}
```