# How to get Example and solution as in the style of the attached jpg file

Tags: numbering, examples, exercises

How to get Example and solution as in the style with boundaries of the attached jpg file.

[image]

```
  \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{exercise,chngcntr}
\counterwithin{Exercise}{chapter}
\counterwithin{Answer}{chapter}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theExercise}{\thechapter.\arabic{Exercise}}
\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}
Prove that $    \frac{1}{2}\Delta(f_{ij}f^{ij}) =\nabla^{k}f^{ij}+f^{ij}f^{k}[2 \nabla_{i}R_{jk}-\nabla_{k}R_{ij}]$
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
Answer 2.2
        \end{Answer}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: `tcolorbox` is quite powerfull.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I am a layman in Latex. Please help me so that I can get automatic Example numbering and Solution after the question with the style as I have attached above. Thanks.

Comment: How to get this?

Comment: @user1942348 Do you want the example numbered without the number of the chapter and the solution without number?

Comment: maybe as a starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254351/36296 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254425/36296

Comment: @CarLaTeX It will be better if I can write ex no according as chapter and solution without no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created the new environment `Example` which puts the `Exercise` one within a `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{arc=0mm,boxrule=1pt,colback=white,colframe=cyan,leftrule=3mm}

\counterwithin{Exercise}{chapter}
\counterwithin{Answer}{chapter}
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theExercise}{\thechapter.\arabic{Exercise}}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\medskip\noindent\textcolor{red}{\textbf{SOLUTION}}\;}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{EXAMPLE}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\noindent\textbf{\ExerciseName\;\ExerciseHeaderNB}}
\newenvironment{Example}{\begin{tcolorbox}\begin{Exercise}}{\end{Exercise}\end{tcolorbox}}
\setlength{\ExerciseSkipBefore}{0pt}
\setlength{\AnswerSkipAfter}{\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{My first set of exercises}
    \begin{Example}
        Prove that $\frac{1}{2}\Delta(f_{ij}f^{ij}) =\nabla^{k}f^{ij}+f^{ij}f^{k}[2\nabla_{i}R_{jk}-\nabla_{k}R_{ij}]$
    \end{Example}
    \begin{Answer}
        From \dots
    \end{Answer}

    \begin{Example}
        Prove that Paulinho is smart.
    \end{Example}
    \begin{Answer}
        All ducks are smart. Paulinho is a duck. Therefore, Paulinho is smart.
    \end{Answer}

    \begin{Example}
        Prove that Paulinho is smart.
    \end{Example}
    \begin{Answer}
        All ducks are smart. Paulinho is a duck. Therefore, Paulinho is smart.
    \end{Answer}

    \chapter{My second set of exercises}
    \begin{Example}
        Prove that Paulinho is smart.
    \end{Example}
    \begin{Answer}
        All ducks are smart. Paulinho is a duck. Therefore, Paulinho is smart.
    \end{Answer}

    \begin{Example}
        Prove that Paulinho is smart.
    \end{Example}
    \begin{Answer}
        All ducks are smart. Paulinho is a duck. Therefore, Paulinho is smart.
    \end{Answer}
\end{document}
```

I hope this is the output you are looking for:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`xsim`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xsim) package with [`tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) (questions and answers stolen from [CarLaTeX's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369173/)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim,tcolorbox,needspace}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/within = section ,
  exercise/the-counter = \thesection.\arabic{exercise} ,
  exercise/template = cyan-box ,
  exercise/name = Example ,
  solution/template = red ,
  solution/print = true
}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{cyan-box}
  {%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[arc=0mm,boxrule=1pt,colback=white,colframe=cyan,leftrule=3mm]
      \textsf{%
        \MakeUppercase{%
          \XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}%
        }%
      }%
      \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}}%
      \quad
  }
  {\end{tcolorbox}}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{red}
  {%
    \par
    \Needspace*{2\baselineskip}
    \noindent
    \textsf{\textcolor{red}{\MakeUppercase{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}}}}%
    \quad
  }
  {\par\bigskip}

\begin{document}

\section{My first set of exercises}
\begin{exercise}
  Prove that $\frac{1}{2}\Delta(f_{ij}f^{ij})
  =\nabla^{k}f^{ij}+f^{ij}f^{k}[2\nabla_{i}R_{jk}-\nabla_{k}R_{ij}]$
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  From \dots
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
  Prove that Paulinho is smart.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  All ducks are smart. Paulinho is a duck. Therefore, Paulinho is smart.
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
  Prove that Paulinho is smart.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  All ducks are smart. Paulinho is a duck. Therefore, Paulinho is smart.
\end{solution}

\section{My second set of exercises}
\begin{exercise}
  Prove that Paulinho is smart.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  All ducks are smart. Paulinho is a duck. Therefore, Paulinho is smart.
\end{solution}

\begin{exercise}
  Prove that Paulinho is smart.
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  All ducks are smart. Paulinho is a duck. Therefore, Paulinho is smart.
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: FYI xsim throws an error in Miktex:

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xsim\xsim.random.code.tex")
! Undefined control sequence.
\xsim_declare_translation:nnn ...claretranslation 
                                                  {#1}{\c__xsim_keyword_pref...
l.357 Happens even with the latest Miktex updates.

Comment: Problem solved,  I had an old translation.sty file that was wasn't updated.